# Jquery not detecting new elements added by Jquery Repeater

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jquery.repeater

Im using a jquery repeater to repeat input fields and **i need to find the name of the last input field added (with the a specific id).**

How im doing it :

```
    $('#addElements').on('click', function() {
        var nameOfLastInput = $("#inputID:last").attr("name");
        console.log(nameOfLastInput);
    });
```

What i get is the name of the first field every time:
[image]

Full working code (needs a js repeater lib):

```
    @section('content')
    <div  id="kt_repeater_1" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px">
        <div data-repeater-list="repeat">
            <div data-repeater-item>
                <input type="text" name="text-input" id="inputID"/>
                <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add" id="addElements"/>
    </div>

    @section('scripts')
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.repeater.js" defer></script>


    <script>

        $('#addElements').on('click', function() {
            var nameOfLastInput = $("#inputID:last").attr("name");
            console.log(nameOfLastInput);
        });
    </script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.repeater.min.js" defer></script>
    @endsection
@endsection
```

Comment: So multiple elements have same ID?

Comment: Add a unique id to every field you add or use id=id[];

Comment: IDs must be unique, so `$("#inputID")` will always get a single element and it will be the first one. `:last` just gets the last of the collection, as there's only 1, it's also the first.   You *could* do `$("[id=inputID]:last")` - or you could do it properly and keep IDs unique: give them a class.

Comment: @freedomn-m classes worked thanks

Comment: @user2962142 I guess I indirectly pointed the same issue